# Color property reverted when selecting a cell in gtk3

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, gtk3

I have a `gtk.TreeViewColumn` that I fill with `gtk.CellRendererText` cells. The font color of each cell is managed by the function `cell_color` using a `set_cell_data_func(...)`.

The problem is that the color changes to white when I select a cell.

How can I prevent this? I tried adding a `cssprovider` to prevent the color change, but failed. I decided to use the `cssprovider` to change the row to red when selected and this works. But I actually don't want any change...

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk as gdk
...

def __init__(self):

    css_provider = gtk.CssProvider()
    css_provider.load_from_data(b"""
            #textv:selected { background-color: #222222; color: red; }
            """)
    gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(gdk.Screen.get_default(), \ 
        css_provider, gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

    ...
    cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
    tvcolumn = gtk.TreeViewColumn(title="Search results")
    tvcolumn.pack_start(cell, True)
    tvcolumn.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 0)
    tvcolumn.set_cell_data_func(cell, self.cell_color)

    textv = gtk.TreeView(name="textv", model=self.showlist)
    textv.append_column(tvcolumn)
    ...

def cell_color(self, comumn, cell, model, iterr, user_data):
    cell.set_property('foreground', '#dddddd')
    if <some condition>:
        cell.set_property('foreground', '#e2e23c')
```